# How can this design be achieved with CSS and 2 images

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am looking for a way to put two images side by side on a webpage with the following attributes.
1)It should look like this
[image]
2)Both have to be links(ex. mysite1.html and mysite2.html)
3)Both should be in black and white
4)On hover one of them should grow a little bit and become colored
5)On click go to mysiteX.html

I am quite sure that there are some templates out there on the internet for this, but I don't know how to name this animation and can't find it.

**EDIT**
I am looking for a template. I did not try this yet, and I don't want to start from 0 because I am quite sure that there is a template which can be used.

Comment: You should ask a question with evidence of what you attempted in order to achieve this goal. We are here to help not to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just had this idea, and I thought that there is a template which can be used, so I don't have to start from 0

Comment: Please share your code, If you tried to do it.

Comment: I edited my question. My opinion is that the community is big enough and someone had already achieved this, so I don't have to do it. Only to change or improve an already existing code

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it is quite easy to use css `clip-path` property. You need polygon shape for that.

Here is a good article about it: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

and here is an example of how to use it to solve your problem: http://jsbin.com/linelegini/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML's [map](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and [area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) tags. They are quite useful when talking about shape wrapping, and with the help of some CSS and Scripting, you can get a fancy VS screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create my desired output, thanks to [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993216/ivan-demchenko).
I am the worst when it comes to CSS so this can be improved a lot.

Using the following CSS with Bootstrap included

```
.l {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%,0% 100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.r {
  left: 540px;
  margin-left: -20%;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%,0% 100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.d {
  position:relative
}
```

With the following HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="d">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
      <img class="pic l" src="http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/images/galleries/618486main_earth_320.jpg" id="leftImage">
      <img class="pic r" src="http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/images/galleries/618486main_earth_320.jpg" id="rightImage">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this JS(the canEnter variable is far from the best solution but it's better than nothing):

```
  window.onload = function(){
    var canEnter = true;
    $('#leftImage')[0].hX2 = $('#leftImage').height() * 2;
    $('#leftImage')[0].h = $('#leftImage').height();

    $('#leftImage').on('mouseenter', function(){
        if (!canEnter)
            return;
        canEnter = false;
        this.style.filter = 'none';
        this.style.zIndex = 2;
        this.style.clipPath = 'none';
        $(this).animate({height: $('#leftImage')[0].hX2}, "fast");
    });
    $('#leftImage').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).animate({height: $('#leftImage')[0].h}, "fast", function(){
            this.style.filter = 'grayscale(100%)';
            this.style.zIndex = 1;
            this.style.clipPath = 'polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%)';
            if (!canEnter)
                canEnter = true;
        });
    });

    $('#rightImage').on('mouseenter', function(){
        if (!canEnter)
            return;
        canEnter = false;
        this.style.filter = 'none';
        this.style.zIndex = 2;
        this.style.clipPath = 'none';
        $(this).animate({height: $('#leftImage')[0].hX2, left: 300}, "fast");
    });
    $('#rightImage').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).animate({height: $('#leftImage')[0].h, left: 540}, "fast", function(){
            this.style.filter = 'grayscale(100%)';
            this.style.zIndex = 1;
            this.style.clipPath = 'polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)';
            if (!canEnter)
                canEnter = true;
        });
    });
  }
```